# Adding a column of categorical variables to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with economical data, separated in rows by years (1991-2016). I am trying to add a column of a categorical variable 'groups' to the data frame, grouping years 1991-1999 in group 1, years 2000-2009 in group 2, and 2010-2016 in group 3.

I have tried adding the column with an if/else statement.

```
wdi$groups <- 
  if(wdi$year > 1990 & wdi$year <2000) {
    1
  }
  if else(wdi$year > 2000 & wdi$year < 2010) {
    2
  }
  else {
    3
  }
```

I get the following error.

the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedError: unexpected 'else' in "  if else"

Comment: [`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/ifelse)`(wdi$year > 190 & wdi$year < 2000, 1, ifelse(wdi$year > 2000 & wdi$year < 2010, 2, 3))`, though: (1) "2000" is never matched, (2) perhaps better: `cut(wdi$year, c(1990, 2000, 2010, Inf), labels = FALSE)` (assuming nothing before 1990).

Comment: `if` can only be used on something that returns exactly one logical, not more. I'm inferring that your `wdi$year` is length greater than 1 (it's a frame, right?), so you need a vectorized approach. `ifelse` works fine, though when you start nesting it heavily (as my first suggestion), it might become cumbersome past 2 or so. `cut` can help here assuming that you really have continuous intervals (not the "2000" gap I mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with `case_when`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df%>%
mutate(group = case_when(year %in% 1991:1999 ~ 1,
                         year %in% 2000:2009 ~ 2,
                         year %in% 2010:2016 ~ 3))
```

Comment: you can also take advantage of the fact that case_when stops evaluation on the first condition returning TRUE. Such as case_when(year  < 1999 ~ 1, year < 2009 ~ 2, T ~ 3)

Comment: Indeed, I just thought the option above would be safer since we haven't seen the actual data.